# measuring a distance on QGIS 2.2. in meters not degrees

Tags: qgis, distance

Im using QGIS 2.2.0 and when I want to measure the distance on a map, the units are in degrees instead of meters. I have tried this :

Right click on layer -> "Save as..." -> CRS: Selected CRS (WGS84)

but nothing has happened.

Does anyone have any ideas?